# Tag Edit Suggestion: Apps Corner

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging, editing

Hie. I noticed there is a tag named **[app-corner](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app-corner)**, which I'm pretty certain should be named **"[apps-corner](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apps-corner)"** corner, after the feature of the same name in Windows Phone settings. Can someone correct the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag has been renamed - might take a little while for the tag pages to update as this is pulled from caches :)